# Make OL Tag from Bottom

Tags: html

**Can anyone help me?** i'm looking for how to make  tag @html code but count the numbers from below. Because what I know is just creating  tags but always counting the numbers from above like this :

```
<ol>
  <li>Aaaa</li>
  <li>Aaaa</li>
  <li>Aaaa</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me help my friend. It might help you ^_^

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The ol reversed attribute</h1>

<ol reversed>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The reversed attribute of the ol tag is not supported in Edge prior version 79.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Terima kasih Om @Dimas Wahyu Notonagoro (y)